# Short Date in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want my query to stop displaying time and just the date. This is what I've tried to far:

```
Query= (from z in ctx.Interactions 
        where z.ActivityDate <= StartDateTo
           && z.ActivityDate >= EndDateTo
           && z.Indepth == false
        select new
               {
                   Date = new DateTime(z.ActivityDate.Year, z.ActivityDate.Month, z.ActivityDate.Day),
                   Subject = z.Subject
               }).ToList();
```

And

```
Query= (from z in ctx.Interactions
        where z.ActivityDate <= StartDateTo
           && z.ActivityDate >= EndDateTo
           && z.Indepth == false
        select new
               {
                   Date = z.ActivityDate.Date,
                   Subject = z.Subject
               }).ToList();
```

And both didn't work.

`LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.` when trying to apply a string method.

Comment: A LINQ query does not _display_ anything. Where do you want to show the date only?

Comment: Well you need to do that where you convert the date/time into a string for displaying.

Comment: Linq doesn't display anything but when i do display it, it displays with the date. It's a binding to the query

Comment: "I want my query to stop displaying time" - `DateTime` doesn't hold any formatting info, so if your `DateTime` field has just Date, its Time part would be set to `00:00:00`. You need to format your `DateTime` object to string. See [Custom Date and Time Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: A `DateTime` has - as the name suggests - a `Date` part and a `Time` part. If you only want to see the `Date` part, you'll have to format it that way (e. g. `Date.ToShortDateString()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to perform the formatting at the time of the binding.  As you don't show the actual binding code, it is hard to *specifically* address your situation but lets look at what happens in your query:

```
Query= (from z in ctx.Interactions
        where z.ActivityDate <= StartDateTo && z.ActivityDate >= EndDateTo && z.Indepth == false
        select new { Date = z.ActivityDate.Date, Subject = z.Subject }).ToList();
```

Once LINQ handles this query, the resulting `Query` variable *should* be of type `List<DateTime>`.  The way you have the query working you would return a list of `DateTime`s in a format like this:

```
2014-04-23 00:00:00
2014-03-28 00:00:00
etc...
```

In order to bind this **without** the time value, you need to call `ToString()` on each element (or the desired element) of the list **at the time of binding**.

Assuming you are using a `ListBox` or something similar you could write the following:

```
foreach (var date in myList) //this is the resultant list from the query
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
```

If you are literally binding to a `DataSource` property, you will need to convert your `List<DateTime>` to a `List<string>` with the formatted values.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `anyDate.ToString("ddMMyyyy");//any preferred format.`

Not sure if that is what you are looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Your queries return objects with Date & Subject properties.

In the Date property you are passing a DateTime object. In order to display the short date you have a "ToShortDateString()" function on a date.

If you dont want to work with a date and prefer selecting a string, then do the conversion inside the linq query.

Use this if you want to return strings:

```
var q = (from z in ctx.Interactions
        where z.ActivityDate <= StartDateTo && z.ActivityDate >= EndDateTo && z.Indepth == false
        select new { Date = z.ActivityDate.Date.ToShortDateString(), Subject = z.Subject }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

[ToShortDateString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx) may help you.

```
Query= (from z in ctx.Interactions
        where z.ActivityDate <= StartDateTo
           && z.ActivityDate >= EndDateTo
           && z.Indepth == false
        select new
               {
                   Date = z.ActivityDate.ToShortDateString(),
                   Subject = z.Subject
               }).ToList();
```

Comment: Having `z.ActivityDate.Date.ToShortDateString()` would still cause the error because of the `Date` in there. `z.ActivityDate.ToShortDateString()` should work instead.

Comment: I tried your recommendation but I got the exception "System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToShortDateString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'
"

Answer (score -1):

convert date into string like below

```
string stringDate=string.empty;
stringDate=Convert.ToDateTime("2014-04-23 00:00:00").ToShortDateString();
```

it will give output like
2014-04-23

Comment: I think you didn't read the question. It's inside a LINQ query.